# PHP Tokenize with a word

Tags: php, token, tokenize, strtok

Hello I'm fairly new to php and I've started using strstok in .txt files. It works just fine until i want to tokenize with a word. I've been working on more complicated (1st year compsci level) program, but the following example will sum up the problem quite well.

For example if I have the string: "Hello world you are very beautiful today" and i want to tokenize using the word "very". If I would echo the two tokens, my desired output would be "Hello world you are beautiful today". However, when I try using a word, I never get that and I haven't found sources that explain how to do this with a simple explanation.

Here is the same thing in code:

```
    <?php
    function strtokTest(){
        $string = "Hello world you are very beautiful today.";
        $token = strtok($string, "very");
        while ($token != false){
            echo "$token";
            $token = strtok("very");
        } 
    }
    ?>
```

If I run this on a php page, the output will be:

```
Hllo wold ou a bautiful on this da.
```

It was funny at first, but now I'm sad. Can anyone tell me a good way to do this?

Thank you,

Alexander W

Comment: According to [PHP documentation](http://us3.php.net/strtok) - `strtok($str, $token)`; splits by **ANY CHARACTER** of the `token`. Not the string. So, You should use `explode($token, $str);` as [@hek2mgl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) accepts only single characters as token delimiters. (Although you passing them all as a string)

You want [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
foreach(explode(' very ', $str) as $token) {
    echo $token;
}
```